# Does order of functions and objects really matter in Angular JS file containing module?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is **`app.js`** from my Angular JS App:

```
var app = angular.module('store',[]); // [] is for dependencies which we don't have yet so it's empty

(function(){
    app.controller('StoreController',function(){
        this.blabla = student;
    });
})();



(function(){
    app.controller('ControllerForArrayOfStudents',function(){
        this.students = student1;
    });
})();

var student = 
{
    name:"Abc Def",
    rollNumber:12,
    isBrilliant: true,
    isMale:false,
    isFemale: false
}



var student1 = 
[
{
    name:"Abc Def",
    rollNumber:12,

},

{
    name:"Ghi",
    rollNumber:13,
}
]
```

This works fine unless I change the order of functions and objects as follows:

```
var app = angular.module('store',[]); // [] is for dependencies which we don't have yet so it's empty

(function(){
    app.controller('StoreController',function(){
        this.blabla = student;
    });
})();

var student = 
{
    name:"Abc Def",
    rollNumber:12,
    isBrilliant: true,
    isMale:false,
    isFemale: false
}


(function(){
    app.controller('ControllerForArrayOfStudents',function(){
        this.students = student1;
    });
})();




var student1 = 
[
{
    name:"Abc Def",
    rollNumber:12,

},

{
    name:"Ghi",
    rollNumber:13,
}
]
```

Error I am getting on changing order is this:
[image]

Does order of functions and objects really matter in Angular JS file containing modules?

Comment: It's a little weird that it works in the 1st case. The variables `student` and `studante1` should be undefined by the time they are accessed within the controller. The attribution is made after the query.

Comment: @Papzord: Yeah, **if** Angular calls those callbacks inline with the `app.controller` function (not asynchronously later), the variables would exist but have the value `undefined` -- in *both* blocks above.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Right, it depends on the function invocation time. They are called later and the value is defined. Good point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How to fix it

That happens because you're missing all the semicolons after the variable declarations. If you add them, it works fine. AngularJs has nothing to do with it.

In the first case it works, because the JavaScript parser of Chrome notices that the next term after the object initializer for `student` is `var`, which could only stand at the beginning of a statement, so it *assumes* that it is a new statement and inserts the semicolon for you thanks to [automatic semicolon insertion](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-automatic-semicolon-insertion).

But it can't do that in your second example, because the `(` after the object initializer is *valid* and looks like the beginning `()` operator that does a function call, expecting what's in front of it to be a function reference. So you need the semicolon, it can't be inserted for you:

```
var app = angular.module('store',[]); // [] is for dependencies which we don't have yet so it's empty

(function(){
    app.controller('StoreController',function(){
        this.blabla = student;
    });
})();

var student = 
{
    name:"Abc Def",
    rollNumber:12,
    isBrilliant: true,
    isMale:false,
    isFemale: false
};  // <======================= here

(function(){
    app.controller('ControllerForArrayOfStudents',function(){
        this.students = student1;
    });
})();

var student1 = [
  {
      name:"Abc Def",
      rollNumber:12,

  },

  {
      name:"Ghi",
      rollNumber:13,
  }
];
```

### About automatic semicolon insertion (ASI)

The standard declares that JavaScript interpretes *must* insert semicolons in the token stream in certain situations, where the syntax is somewhat clear and a newline is involved. ([Automatic semicolon insertion](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-automatic-semicolon-insertion))
In the first snippet all the missing semicolons are in those special cases, as they do not form a valid grammar without semicolons, so they are inserted. (The statement cannot continue with another `var`, or an eof)
In the second one, the following token is a `(`, which is allowed by *some production of the grammar*, and is *not a restricted production*.
Specifically it is a `CallExpression`, of the first form, as an `ObjectLiteral` is a `MemberExpression`, as stated in the syntactic grammar.

P.S.: Moral of the story: use semicolons. Semicolons introduce redundancy in the grammar, and programming languages need a healthy level of redundancy in order to be able to notice typos. A language with no redundancy would mean that any random sequence of characters would be a valid code.

Comment: JS allows skipping semicolon if you only have 1 statement per line. I don't see any instances where the semicolon is required but was left off

Comment: `VariableStatement : var VariableDeclarationList ;` By the way, if the standard allows it, then it is a chrome bug. Give me a sec to investigate it

Comment: You are right that I didnt think about auto semicolon insertion when I posted my answer, but that definitely made the code work. However, you guys are not right either, in the second case it is not valid to insert semicolons automatically. So thanks for pointing this out! See my update.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder "The source `a = b + c` \n
`(d + e).print()`
is not transformed by automatic semicolon insertion, because the parenthesised expression that begins the second line can be interpreted as an argument list for a function call" see http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.9.2

Comment: I simply didn't believe that it was becoming a function call (because of the `var`), but `http://jsparser.meteor.com` agrees with your analysis above. (And @Rouby's, saw that when I came back from jsparser.) **Big** +1, for the answer, and for the doggedness.

Comment: *"Moral of the story: use semicolons."* Big time. This is probably the best example of that moral (I've been preaching it for years) I've ever seen.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing semicolons after your variable declarations. In most cases this would be covered by [*automatic semicolon insertion*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.9), but because in your case a parenthesised expression follows (`(function(){})()`) the interpreter will treat this as an argumentlist for a function-call. This results in your error :)

So if you just put semicolons after your variable declarations, everything is ok.

Answer (score -1):

as it is pointed out angularjs has nothing to do with it but it is best practice to write the functions and objects in order and if you do not want to use ';' try coffescript or have a look at this https://www.codecademy.com/blog/78-your-guide-to-semicolons-in-javascript