# Ternary condition after variable declaration considered bad practice when using StandardJS

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

I've run into a somewhat confusing issue when using JS standard (no semi-colons) and I think I'm doing something wrong with the following code:

```
window.onload = function () {
  var menu = document.getElementById('menu')
  (window.pageYOffset > 10)
    ? menu.classList.add('scrolled')
    : menu.classList.remove('scrolled')
}
```

That produces a `document.getElementById is not a function` error in the console, and adding a semi-colon at the end of the var declaration fixes it. What I would like to know is, if the code above is not a good pattern or wrong in some point if JS standard of coding is being used.

**UPDATE:** Alright, so I guess the proper way, standardjs-wise, of doing the above would be:

```
  var menu = document.getElementById('menu')
  ;(window.pageYOffset > 10)
    ? menu.classList.add('scrolled')
    : menu.classList.remove('scrolled')
```

Link: https://standardjs.com/rules.html#semicolons

Comment: This is case where you need the semicolon to be there, as it cannot be sure where you intended to start or end your statement, since it now does this: `(document.getElementById('menu'))(window.pageYOffset > 10)`, and `document.getElementById('menu')` does not return a function, yet it looks like a function call.

Comment: add a ";" after ('scrolled')

Comment: @Mario that's not the issue, but its sound advice.

Comment: Both leaving the semicolon (relying to ASI) and using ternary operator instead of `if` is bad practice. I remember the semicolon issue coming up everywhere (like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32606852/does-order-of-functions-and-objects-really-matter-in-angular-js-file-containing/32607419#32607419), so I suggest you to use them.

Comment: It's definitely not a good pattern to use the ternary operator instead of a simple `if` statement if you don't care about the result value of the expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in how JS needs to interpret your code without semicolons here:

```
var menu = document.getElementById('menu')
(window.pageYOffset > 10)
    ? menu.classList.add('scrolled')
    : menu.classList.remove('scrolled')
```

After removing the spaces you can reorganise it like this:

```
var menu = document.getElementById('menu')(window.pageYOffset > 10)
    ? menu.classList.add('scrolled')
    : menu.classList.remove('scrolled');
```

So now JS will try to call the *not-a-function* `document.getElementById('menu')` as a function to see if it returns a value and then evaluate your `if`, and at that point your error pops up.

Comment: I see. I guess majority of coders, as good practice/pattern, would go with using a full `if-else` statement in this case instead of a ternary operator?

Comment: @madastro This pattern has its uses, but most would tell you to use it for a quick assignment if/else, and not for actual functional logic. It's either way, just keep in mind that JS was not designed to lack semicolons. For example, I accidentally did something like this today: `e.addListener('a', e => {}) \n\n [ a, b, c ].forEach`, and it also error-ed out looking for an indexed element in the value returned from addListener.  So for JS, you are better of with semicolons.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea would be to make your ternary more specific to what you are actually switching between and use the return value to select the method:

```
var menu = document.getElementById('menu')
menu.classList[window.pageYOffset > 10 ? 'add' : 'remove']('scrolled')
```

That way you don't have to repeat yourself and you sort of side step this problem all-together.